# SQL Server EXECUTE AS trouble

Tags: sql-server-2008, security

I'm missing something while trying to make my stored procedure use `EXECUTE AS`. The stored procedure is reading data from `source_db`, aggregates it and stores result in `target_db`.

The sp itself is in `target_db`. I have a dedicated login and map it to users in both `source_db` and `target_db` for sp's owner (so there is a user `app_agent` in `source_db` and in `target_db` for login `app_agent`).

If I log in as `app_agent`, and execute

```
EXEC target_db.app_agent_schema.import_data
```

everything works fine. But if I change

```
ALTER PROCEDURE app_agent_schema.import_data WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` (or `AS SELF`)
```

and try executing it, it throws

> *The server principal "app_agent" is not able to access the database
>   "source_db" under the current security context.*

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Could someone point out my error?

Thanks

**Update** 
After doing some research, I found that `ALTER DATABASE target_db SET TRUSTWORTHY ON` solves the problem, but that doesn't seem as the right solution to me...

Comment: I think the answer is using the *database*-level [cross-database ownership chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) option. I was able to reproduce the error in your scenario, but there aren't enough details given to know if I reproduced it exactly... the CDOC option didn't work for me, but try it out and see if that does it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is explained in [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The EXECUTE AS context is trusted only in the current database and allowing it to spill over to other databases is a escalation of privilege attack vector.

There are two solutions, both described in the article linked above:

- the easy one is to mark the database TRUSTWORTHY: `ALTER DATABASE [source_db] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;`. Although easy, is also dangerous in as it makes the `dbo` of `source_db` a de-facto `sysadmin`.
- the safe one is use code signing, see [Call a procedure in another database](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/) for an example. This is more complex, but is 100% buletproff security.

Answer (score 0):

Which user runs  the ALTER PROCEDURE command? It might have set the Owner (self) access level to that user, not the one you intended.

Comment: The same user who created procedure (`app_agent`). If I have procedure created by `app_agent` without `execute as owner/self`, log in as `app_agent`, SP executes properly. If I add `EXECUTE AS SELF` (again, the same user), and log in even as `app_agent`, I get `...is not able to access the database...`