# Minimal Permissions to Create an Application Database and Database Owner

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration

I wish to write (or borrow if you have one) a script template for creating an application database and associated logins. The script is to be run in CI pipelines and on developer desktops.

Possibly influenced by postgres but also by [MS maybe-saying that assigning ownership to a disabled login is best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#best-practice) I wish to assign ownership of the database to some insignificant login created for the purpose:

```sql
Create Login appname_owner With Password = 'randomlygeneratedpassword';
Alter Login appname_owner Disable
Create Database appname  ;
Alter Authorization On database::appname To appname_owner ;
```

**Question**: What is the minimal set of permissions that will allow a CI login to do this?

- I believe that `Create Any Database` and `Alter Any Login` are minimal for create login & database. [ I can't say I'm happy with CI scripts needing `Alter Any Login`. It would be nicer to restrict alterable Logins to some group or role defined for the purpose.]
- But I'm stumped on `Alter Authorization`. It seems I need  `Grant Impersonate On Login::appname_owner To CILogin`, which the CILogin can't grant to itself, not even for a login it has just created.

How can I resolve this,

- without the CI scripts using an `sa` login and
- preferably, without granting the CILogin Impersonation rights on all logins to the server

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be achieved by creating a user based on a certificate and [Signing a stored procedure by using a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-signing-a-stored-procedure-by-using-a-certificate):

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE MyInpersonationCert   
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y'  
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate to do a test',   
   EXPIRY_DATE = '20261031';  
GO 

CREATE LOGIN login_from_cert FROM CERTIFICATE MyInpersonationCert;
GO

--It might be a little bit too much permission, but I'm tired and it's late at night.
--You'll figure out the proper privileges for this login ;)
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER login_from_cert;
GO
```

With the login from the certificate having the privileges to create and manipulate the objects you need you can create the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE impersonate_procedure
    @database_name nvarchar(128),
    @login_name nvarchar(128),
    @login_password nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
        
    --add some verification on the received parameters to avoid SQL Injection (still tired)
    
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    
    SET @sql = '
        CREATE LOGIN ' + @login_name + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @login_password + ''';
        ALTER LOGIN ' + @login_name + ' DISABLE;
        CREATE DATABASE ' + @database_name + ';
        ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON database::' + @database_name + ' TO ' + @login_name + ';';
    
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
    
END;
GO

ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.impersonate_procedure
    BY CERTIFICATE MyInpersonationCert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y';  
GO
```

Now you can grant execute to the login used for the CI scripts on `dbo.impersonate_procedure`. Your login will be able to execute the procedure, but not to explicitly issue a `CREATE DATABASE` or `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, I think this puts me on the right track. I think for the verification the simplest might be a server role for 'is a CI login' and another server role for 'logins that CI is allowed to impersonate inside this procedure'. I'll work on that line.

Comment: Is signing a procedure 'the' way to make an sp execute with borrowed permissions — was there no way to do this before certificates?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll, glad I could help. No, it's not the only way to borrow privileges. Another possible way to do it (and one I struggled to use and couldn't make it work for your request) is to use `EXECUTE AS` clause on the [create procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement. See the post [Execute permission denied on object sp_start_job](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/execute-permission-denied-on-object-sp-start-job), it helped me to achieve this solution.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll, were you able to solve your problem with this or any other method?

Comment: Hi, Yes! Sorry for the delayed acceptance: I was trying to do something slightly different to what you proposed and couldn't get  _exactly_ what I wanted. However,  your approach works and answers the problem

Comment: [ What I wanted was to just the bare minimum `alter authorization` inside the signed proc, And without the signer having to be a sysadmin. I don't think it can be done. So what I finished with was essentially what you have, plus a second signed proc for Drop database & logins ]