# How to allow an SQL-ID to access one database through a view in another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, view

I have 2 databases in MS-SQL Server 2012. The first database, ‘DatabaseA’, is accessed by multiple databases including my second database ‘DatabaseB’. I have a view called ‘vwDB_B’ in ‘DatabaseB’ that joins/filters some information from both ‘DatabaseA’ and ‘DatabaseB’ (The view is set to run under an SQL-id that has access to both ‘DatabaseA’ and ‘DatabaseB’. Both DBs are on the same server. DatabaseB accesses objects in DatabaseA through their fully qualified names.

Now, we have an SQL-id that will be used by external users called ‘ExternalID’. This SQL-id should be able to retrieve data from ‘vwDB_B’. How can I achieve it?

If I give SELECT access to the ‘ExternalID’ on the ‘vwDB_B’ view, I get an error message that the ID doesn’t have the access to ‘DatabaseA’. I don’t want to grant read-only access to ‘ExternalID’ (or add it to a read-only role) on ‘DatabaseA’ because this DB has some sensitive information and I only want this id to access the information provided by my ‘vwDB_B’ view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grant access to the view without granting any rights on the underlying tables using [Ownership Chaining](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In this scenario you would need to enable [Cross Database Ownership Chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-cross-database-access-in-sql-server), and grant the user access to the target database, but not SELECT on any of the tables.

Comment: Enabling Cross DB Ownership Chains did help but in itself was not sufficient. Even after further research, I still couldn't get the view working. So I changed the View into a Stored Procedure and had to use the Impersonation to get this working. Not an ideal solution but we were ultimately fine with it. Got help from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304(v=sql.105).aspx), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/sql-server-execute-as-trouble). Thanks David.